# Flag menu does not fully show on mobile

Tags: feature-request, flags

On some mobiles the flag option/menu does not fully show all options and would not scroll down
I find myself switching between full site and mobile just to flag a post.

It there a better way to see all the flag menu options with out switching between full site and mobile site.

I would like to request that this issue be fixed or an alternative provided

Comment: You're on the app, right? (For tagging purposes, iOS or Android?)

Comment: @StephenLeppik since OP mentioned "switching between full site and mobile just to flag a post", it seems on the mobile browser instead of the app.

Comment: That said, it'd be better if you could provide the OS version and the browser version...

Comment: @AndrewT. on the other hand, I can't reproduce this on mobile-web, whereas the app was notorious for its lack of moderation features.

Comment: To clarify am on android 6.0 chrome browser

Comment: In that case, can you provide screenshots?